# Django Admin - Create a Model with User Inline

Tags: python, django, django-admin, inline-formset

Hi i have several model having OneToOne Relationship with User.

There's a way to make inline user creation within the model creation admin page?

Models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #other stuff

class Provider(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        #other stuff
```

Admins.py

```
class UserInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = User


class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [UserInline]

admin.site.register(Employee, EmployeeAdmin)
```

This way i have this:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/organization/employee/
>   'UserInline.fk_name' refers to field 'user' that is missing from model
>   'auth.User'.

I know the inline models need to have FK relationship with the other model.

Should i customize User model?
Am i missing something or this implementation cannot be done?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you expect inlines to behave when it's a OnetoOne relationship? Why use it at all if you can't add more than one??

Comment: What the error message says is that you need to change OnetoOneField to Foreignkey

Comment: Sorry the problem still remain the same, i think OneToOne it the same as ForeignKey with unique=True. I think the problem is the direction of the relationship. In this the User Model had to have the fk to the other model.